# How many of \documentclass exist?

Tags: document-classes, class-options

Sorry for my trivial question but I am curious to know how many `\documentclass` exist. I use generally, `article`, `standalone`, `book`, `report`, `beamer`, but I see in many question also other `\documentclass` like `\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}` or other forms.

> I did not find a complete list of all existing `\documentclass` and what are their function. Is there a complete collection where I can understand the significance and the output?

Comment: A specific answer as to the *count* of `\documentclass`es available is not possible, as new ones might be created as we speak. :-|

Comment: @Werner Thank you very much for your link. Hence there are many documentclass. I have not seen \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}...now I see and add my answer if I am able.

Comment: A related question is "How many different document classes named Thesis exist?"

Comment: @Werner I have seen this link ...https://github.com/latextemplates/LNCS/blob/master/paper.tex but I have not understand nothing :-).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Kindest John I do not know. I wrote my thesis with Microsoft Word 97 :-(

Comment: today in texllive there are 531: $ pwd; find . -name \*.cls | wc -l
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex
531

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I  didn't think there were that many but are most of them related to theses or even formats that are used by home publishers? I thank you very much.

Comment: no idea, you could generate the list just as easily (I used find but searching for  .cls in windows would also work)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was not aware of this.

Comment: I use the same words or similar of @Bernard in Math.SE: *"The downvoter struck again"* 